# Philips PicoPix PPX4935 + PS4 = Sound Delay

Tags: projector, ps4

I have noticed that there is a slight sound delay when watching YouTube videos or Netflix on my PicoPix PPX4935 projector through the latest PS4 Slim. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If the PS4 functions fine through a different video display, then the issue is your projector.  That's not a gaming issue, I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe try the projector on your computer and play Netflix/YouTube to check the projector as well

Comment: @JCTechie it works fine on everything except the PS4

Comment: @Arthur well that is very odd, maybe try changing the FPS of the ps4, I don't have one to mess with but I found this here and in order to fix audio lag on blu-ray you can change the FPS. Maybe that will work for you too (http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Consoles-Peripherals/PS4-blu-ray-audio-out-of-sync/td-p/43360932)

Comment: @Arthur also, your projector might be to blame, change the settings of the projector to "Game mode" or "Movie mode" and see if that helps any.

Comment: @JCTechie there is no game or movie mode :(

Comment: @Arthur Did you try changing the resolution of the PS4?

Comment: @Arthur Make sure you're running the latest system software on your PS4  (https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps4/).  See if this resolves the audio/video sync issue.

Comment: @misha256 it is running the latest

Comment: @Arthur And also are you running the latest firmware on the projector (http://www.project-your-life.com/firmware/ppx4935/EU)

Comment: @misha256 yes, I am